# Getting URL to uploaded file on Box.com

Tags: c#, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I have successfully been able to upload a file Sample.pdf using a C# program utilizing the Box API.
(client_id, client_secret, code, POSTMAN, etc)

```
 BoxApi.V2.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuthToken newToken = default(BoxApi.V2.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuthToken);

        clientID = "blah blah";
        clientSecret = "blah blah";

        TokenProvider tokenProvider = new TokenProvider(clientID, clientSecret);

        StreamReader streamReader = default(StreamReader);
        streamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\BoxApiRefreshToken.txt");
        oldRefreshToken = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();

        newToken = tokenProvider.RefreshAccessToken(oldRefreshToken);
        BoxManager boxManager = new BoxManager(newToken.AccessToken);

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\BoxApiRefreshToken.txt");
        streamWriter.Write(newToken.RefreshToken);
        streamWriter.Close();

        Folder rootFolder = default(Folder);

        rootFolder = boxManager.GetFolder(Folder.Root);

        BoxApi.V2.Model.File file = boxManager.CreateFile(rootFolder, attachedFilename, ConvertStreamToByteArray(stream));
```

Once uploaded, I was just wondering how can I retrieve the public URL to access this file in C# program? I assumed sharedlink is a way but I am not sure how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make a PUT call on the same file-id that you just got back from your upload. Set the Shared-link section of the JSON with the shared-link permissions that you want.  Assuming you have privileges to create the shared-link, it will come back in the response to your PUT request.

Comment: Peter, can you please provide a small piece of code? Much appreciated.

Comment: var fileId = boxManager.GetFile(file.Id);
            
            var sharedLink = new SharedLink()
            {
                Permissions = new Permissions() { CanDownload = true, CanPreview = true }
            };

            boxManager.ShareLink(fileId, sharedLink);

            Console.WriteLine("Shared Link is " + sharedLink.DownloadUrl);     The downloadurl is null